# jqgrid setting page of grid

Tags: jqgrid

When a user selects a cell, I have the following code which goes to a window.location

```
                 beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                 var $td = $(e.target).closest("td"),
                 iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]);
                 if (this.p.colModel[iCol].name === 'FlSaved') {
                 var pagenum = $('#reportList').getGridParam('page');
                 var rownum = 200;
                     alert(pagenum);
                     alert(rownum);
                 window.location = "/Plt/FileUpload/" + '?id=' + encodeURIComponent(rowid) + '&pagenum=' + pagenum;
                 }
```

Note how I am passing the pagenum. The reason why I am passing the page number is because when the user finishes with what they need 
to do at window.location, I need the user to go back to the grid page that they were at.

To do this, I am doing the loadComplete where I set the value of the page but does not seem to be working.

```
      loadComplete: function (data) {

      if ('@TempData["pageNum"]') {

         $("#rpList").trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:pagenum}]);
}
```

Where is the best place of do the trigger reloadGrid at?

Comment: Nate did Olegs, answer help you?  Should I use the loadComplete function as well?  I have a similar problem that I can't seem to resolve.  It is almost exactly the same as a matter of fact.  In fact, I tried Oleg's solution and I seem to still only go back to the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear for me when `'@TempData["pageNum"]'` will be set, when it will be cleared and whether the code will be hold in the cache of the web browser. If we forget about the questions I have one important remark to your code: if you use `.trigger("reloadGrid", ...)` inside of `loadComplete` you should place the call of `trigger` inside of `setTimeout`. It will allows to process till the end the current loadiong of the grid before starting the next loading initialized by `.trigger("reloadGrid", ...)`. So the code could be about the following:

```js
loadComplete: function (data) {
    ...
    if (/*some condition*/) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(this).trigger("reloadGrid",[{page: pagenum}]);
        }, 50);
    }
    ...
}
```

Event the usage of `0` instead of `50` is not the same as the usage of `.trigger("reloadGrid",...)` without `setTimeout`.

Comment: oleg.  I tried your solution as an answer to my question which was almost exactly the same...  I keep loading the first page unfortunately
"http://localhost:19283/Encounters/GetAjaxPagedGridData/?popId=2&_search=false&nd=1362171806222&rows=15&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc"
Notice how my page is still one?  Even though I attempt to set it to two... I am at my wits end here.

Comment: Oleg, can we set the page before the xHR request is sent?  That is what I want to do.  Maybe in the beforeRequest event?  If so how?  I am stuck trying to figure this out.

Comment: @DmainEvent: You can use `serializeGridData` callback to change **any** data which will be sent to the server inclusive `page`. I still suppose that real origin of your problem is in another place.